# Whats the meaning of this korean name in english?

Tags: names

Whats the meaning of this korean name in english?

신제상

Or like the closest meaning it can have

Comment: have you tried anything to find out? Is there any reason meaning of this particular name is significant?

Comment: It might help if you know the hanja version of the name.

Comment: The hanja is 新年奖 but i still am not sure

Comment: That would be read as 신연장 in Korean, so the second/third characters don't match.  According to https://namu.wiki/w/%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%EC%9D%98%20%EC%84%B1%EC%94%A8%EB%B3%84%20%EC%9D%B8%EA%B5%AC%20%EB%B6%84%ED%8F%AC there are only 74(!) people in Korea who uses 新 as a family name.  So either you got all characters wrong, or maybe the person is actually not Korean and 신제상 is the closest Korean approximation for the person's real name in their native language.

Answer (score 1):

Korean names usually have an equivalent Hanja (Chinese character) for each letter, and they have their own interpretations of the meaning somewhat distinct from the ways Chinese people would interpret them.

Moreover, it's almost impossible to figure out the meaning of the names of Korean people unless you know which Hanja they use. Sometimes, you wouldn't understand what the name means EVEN IF YOU KNEW which specific hanja they use.

You had better ask the very person what his or her name means. Or, you should try someone who named the person.